# Como usar scrapy em páginas asp.net

Tags: python, python-3.x, asp.net, web-scraping, scrapy

Bom pessoal, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Tenho que baixa o arquivo excel do produto que contem a descrição "Maíz", Tipo de producto "Los Démas. En grano." e Comercialização "A granel con hasta un 15 % embolsado", desse  [Site](https://dinem.agroindustria.gob.ar/dinem_fob.fob_consultaproductos.aspx#)

Usando as libraries requests e beautifulsoup eu estava conseguindo extrair as informações da Grid, porém, não estava conseguindo fazer oq eu queria, que é justamente clicar no segundo botão "Exporta informacion Diária".

Analisando a aba "Network" da DeveloperTools ele faz duas chamadas, sendo uma delas criando um link temporário e então, esse link temporário redireciona para o arquivo .xls.

[image: Após clicar no botão de download]

Após não conseguir com fazer o que eu queria com libraries Requests e BeautifulSoup, parti então para o famoso Scrapy.

Já consegui extrair dados de diversas páginas com Scrapy, mas ainda sim, não tive nenhum êxito em extrair a página em asp.net.

Enfim, apenas queria que alguém me apontasse para a direção certa, sem necessidade de códigos.

Por acaso eu tenho que enviar um Post Request com as informações que eu quero? Se sim, como eu poderia fazer isso e então baixar o arquivo .xls?

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scrapy` é um módulo que combina o `twisted.web` para baixar as páginas e o `BeautifulSoup` ou o `lxml` para parseá-las.

O seu problema é que o botão que você quer clicar, provavelmente, na verdade não existe mesmo na página! É bem provável que as páginas do site que você quer usar, assim como muitas outras na internet, são disponibilizadas incompletas, sem todos os elementos, e só depois esses elementos são colocados na página através de código feito em javascript que é executado em seu navegador após o carregamento.

Portanto, ao inspecionar o código da página usando o seu navegador, o javascript já terá executado e completado os elementos de forma dinâmica, por isso você encontrará o botão lá. Como nem `BeautifulSoup` e nem `lxml` executam javascript, na página que eles parsearam na memória ao rodar o script o botão não existe.

Isso é muito comum nas páginas da web hoje em dia, que são bastante dinâmicas. Te deixando com duas opções:

1. Analisar o código javascript da página e descobrir onde ele cria o botão. Ou então analisar o que o botão faz. Você pode ir lendo e acompanhando o código javascript manualmente até encontrar uma forma de imitar o que ele faz ao clicar nesse botão, quais parâmetros passar, etc. Em seguida escreva código em python para simular essas ações. Não é uma tarefa fácil mas o código ficaria bastante otimizado pois seria código python sem precisar abrir um navegador de verdade, que seria a segunda opção:
2. Utilizar um navegador de verdade, que **rode javascript**. A biblioteca `Selenium` permite que você abra e controle uma janela de navegador real através do seu script. Como a página abrirá em um navegador verdadeiro, o javascript vai funcionar e você consegue clicar no botão. O lado negativo é que abrir um navegador é pesado e lento, além de carregar vários elementos e imagens desnecessárias ao processo, portanto, não seria tão eficiente quanto acessar diretamente a fonte.